# How to handle an object instance in the state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a class like this:

```
class Outcome {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.inProgress = "";
        this.success = null;
        this.messages = [];
    }

    addMessage(type, text) {
        this.messages.push({
            type,
            text
        });
    }

    getMessagesByType(type) {
        return this.messages.filter((message) => message.type === type);
    }
}
```

In my React component I imported it, and I would like to use it like this:

```
submit() {
    let outcome = new Outcome("submit");
    outcome.inProgress = true;

    this.setState({
        outcome // Save in state so I can show a spinner
    });

    if (!formsDataValid) {
        outcome.inProgress = false;
        outcome.success = false;
        outcome.addMessage("error", "Data are not valid");
        this.setState({
            outcome
        });
        return;
    }

    fetch().then((response) => {
        outcome.inProgress = false;
        if (response.ok) {
            outcome.success = true;
            outcome.addMessage("success", "Operation correctly performed");
        } else {
            outcome.success = false;
            outcome.addMessage("error", response.error);
        }
        this.setState({
            outcome
        });
    });
}
```

then in render I can check the result in this way:

```
render() {
    {this.state.outcome?.inProgress ?
        "Spinner here"
    : this.state.outcome?.messages.length > 0 ?
        "Here render the messages"
    : null}

    <button type="submit" disabled={this.state.outcome?.success || false}>Submit button</button>
}
```

This should works, **but the problem is that** in handle submit, when I'm doing for example `outcome.success = false;` **it will edit the state directly, because the object is a reference**.

Is there a clean way to do that without edit the state directly? I tried

```
this.setState({
    outcome: { ...outcome }
});
```

but in this way it will remove the methods of the class in the object it clone in to the state.

I know we should use React Hooks, but the components is an old component and we have no time to change that.

Comment: The sequential `setState` calls will be batched anyway; you're not modifying state directly--it hasn't been set yet. The code could be restructured to make this more clear: create the state, check `formsDataValid` and update the object if needed, set the state, and return if needed. That could be extracted to a method to keep `submit` a little cleaner. The `setState` from the `fetch` is *not* sequential and won't be affected by the state set "output" of the fetch handler.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to create a method that can produce a copy of an `Outcome`. Essentially when you do `{...outcome}` you're losing the prototype chain from `outcome` and only copying its members.

```
class Outcome {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.inProgress = "";
        this.success = null;
        this.messages = [];
    }

    addMessage(type, text) {
        this.messages.push({
            type,
            text
        });
    }

    getMessagesByType(type) {
        return this.messages.filter((message) => message.type === type);
    }

    clone() {
       const result = new Outcome(this.name);
       result.inProgress = this.inProgress;
       result.success = this.success;
       result.messages = this.messages;
       return result;
    }
}
```

You could then use it like this:

```
this.setState({
    outcome: outcome.clone();
});
```

There's also a generic way to do this that'll work for (most) classful objects.

```
function cloneInstance(obj) {
  return Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj), Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(obj));
}
```

If you want to be able to easily mutate the result too for more of a functional style, I'd probably use something like this:

```
function immutableModify(obj, cb = o => o) {
  const result = Object.create(
    Object.getPrototypeOf(obj), 
    Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(obj)
  );
  cb(result);
  return result;
}
```

which can then be used like

```
this.setState({
  outcome: immutableModify(outcome, outcome => outcome.name = "test")
});
```